# Fusion builder is not working in WordPress 4.9.6 version

Tags: wordpress

I need your help, I am using the Wordpress 4.9.6 version, But Fusion Builder is not working on my WordPress version. Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

It shows the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined" error.

Thanks